# how to read the body of the HttpServletRequest where the request header content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded in java

Tags: servlets

My `HTTPServletRequest` contains the following information..

```
headers: 
  Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
  X-Chargify-Webhook-Signature: b048ad28f573829f52f05208aa522a6f
  X-Chargify-Webhook-Id: "8233897"
  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  Accept: "*/*; q=0.5, application/xml"
  Content-Length: "47"
body: payload[chargify]=testing&id=8233897&event=test
```

Now, how to read the body from the request and separate the body into key/value pairs?

Answer (score 0):

In `Servlet service()` method is having `HttPServlerRequest` Object.

By using this Request object call `request.getParameter(paramName)`, you can get value from request object

[Refference](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/127.html)

Comment: got them all using request.getParameterMap() and done some iteration to log the keys versus the values